# Transfer learning using VGG16 MNIST Digits

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to perform transfer learning on the MNIST digits. I am interested in obtaining the logits and using it for gradient based attacks. But for some reason, the kernel keeps dying even though my computer is an apple m2max computer with GPU enabled. I also tried colab with GPU the same issue. The dataset is not too learng and I am reusing imagenet weights. How can I resolve this issue?

```
class VGG16TransferLearning(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, base_model, models):
    super(VGG16TransferLearning, self).__init__()
    #base model
    self.base_model = base_model

   # other layers
   self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
   self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')
   self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')
   self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
   self.layers_list = [self.flatten, self.dense1, self.dense2, self.dense3]
  
  #instantiate the base model with other layers
  self.model = models.Sequential(
    [self.base_model, *self.layers_list]
   )

def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
  activation_list = []
  out = args[0]
  
  for layer in self.model.layers:
    out = layer(out)
    activation_list.append(out)
  if kwargs['training']:
   return out
  else:
   prob = tf.nn.softmax(out)
   return out, prob
```

and here is the instantiation of the class above:

```
base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=x_train[0].shape)
```

base_model.trainable = False

my input shape is (75,75,3)

here is the compile and fit methods

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
```

model = VGG16TransferLearning(base_model, models)

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

This is the error I get each time i call the fit method:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel for Untitled.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is from the configuration of my computer. I guess, tensorflow was not seeing the GPU of my mac even though list physical devices evaluates to 1. But it is resolved now and everything works fine.